# FireTray stopped working on Thunderbird

Tags: 14.04, gnome, thunderbird

Using Thunderbird 31.3.0 with FireTray 0.5.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Gnome.
When I reduce my Thunderbird window it doesn't go the tray icons area,and when I close the window it stops Thunderbird.
Occurred after restarting my machine, every thing was working fine before.

Anybody faced the same issue or knows a better way to minimize Thunderbird to tray ?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested, [here on GitHub](https://github.com/foudfou/FireTray/issues/147#issuecomment-68603942) is the instruction for FireTray 0.5.4:

> For the fix, try **Preferences > Advanced > Config Editor**
>
> search extensions.firetray.with_appindicator, set it to false, and restart
> Thunderbird.

After applying that, everything works as it used to. The regression seems to be caused by porting the addon to Unity and Plasma 5 with new app indicators.

**PS** Note that this is not a solution for KDE5. In that DE you need to leave the setting as true and pray, otherwise you'll get no icon at all.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped firetray and used MinimizeToTray revived (MinTrayR) 1.1.2 instead.
It worked fine for me, I can minimize Thunderbird window to tray icon area back.
Hope it may help someone !